# Pandas dataframe/csv pivot table, how to eliminate series based on first or last values?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have data saved in a pandas dataframe (made from a csv file via pd.read_csv), which is currently in 3 columns. These tell you the patient ID, how many days since their first visit to the hospital, and their score on a test at the hospital.

```
| Patient | Days | Score |
|---------|------|-------|
|       1 |    0 |    30 |
|       1 |  100 |    30 |
|       1 |  150 |    29 |
|       2 |    0 |    24 |
|       2 |   45 |    22 |
|       2 |   95 |    20 |
|       2 |  130 |    16 |
|       3 |    0 |    30 |
|       3 |  125 |    29 |
|       3 |  225 |    28 |
```

I would like to scan through the data, and any time the patient had a score below 28 on the **first** date they visited the hospital, remove that patient from the dataframe entirely. (or, create a new dataframe lacking all of these patients).

For the data above this would mean removing patient '2', leaving us with the final data of

```
| Patient | Days | Score |
|---------|------|-------|
|       1 |    0 |    30 |
|       1 |  100 |    30 |
|       1 |  150 |    29 |
|       3 |    0 |    30 |
|       3 |  125 |    29 |
|       3 |  225 |    28 |
```

I previously tried converting the Dataframe to a pivot_table, but was having some issues with the indexing. In total there are about 4,000 patients. What is the cleanest way to do this using Pandas/NumPy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [9]: df[df.groupby('Patient')['Score'].transform('first').ge(28)]
Out[9]:
   Patient  Days  Score
0        1     0     30
1        1   100     30
2        1   150     29
7        3     0     30
8        3   125     29
9        3   225     28
```

or:

```
In [20]: df.groupby('Patient').filter(lambda x: x.iloc[0, df.columns.get_loc('Score')] >= 28)
Out[20]:
   Patient  Days  Score
0        1     0     30
1        1   100     30
2        1   150     29
7        3     0     30
8        3   125     29
9        3   225     28
```

**Timing** for 100.000 rows DF:

```
In [22]: df = pd.concat([df] * 10**4, ignore_index=True)

In [23]: df.shape
Out[23]: (100000, 3)

In [24]: %timeit df[df.groupby('Patient')['Score'].transform('first').ge(28)]
16.8 ms ± 617 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [25]: %timeit df.groupby('Patient').filter(lambda x: x.iloc[0, df.columns.get_loc('Score')] >= 28)
49.9 ms ± 1.34 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: @saxophone37, glad i could help :)

Comment: In .transform('first').ge(28) , what does the ge stand for? Is there an easy way to use this for other operations? i.e. if ge is greater/equal to, is there a less than version I could use to remove items less than a number? And could I put other equations/functions inside () rather than 28? Thanks again.

Comment: @saxophone37, `.ge()` - "greater or equal" - it's the same as `>=`, so we can do: `df[df.groupby('Patient')['Score'].transform('first') >= 28]`